# How to disable right click in Google Ads?

Tags: adsense

I tried to disable right click using many Plugins. I succeeded to disable right click on everything except on my ads.

From few days some spammers are clicking my ads in Bulk. I removed all adcodes from my site and purchased "AdSense Click Fraud Monitor". It helped me a lot to get rid of this issue since am able to set a click limit. I noticed those spam IPs in statcounter & block list in plugin when they again tried to click on my  ad.

Soon they found a way to harm my AdSense instead clicking my ads they start opening ads in new tab. On mobile device to open that on new tab. I'm very much frustrated and scared because of this issue. Since my major income from my blog is AdSense and site on which am facing issue has good Google ranking.

How can I get rid of this issue? I don't want to lose my AdSense.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Maybe you are better off asking the question in a Google related forum.

Comment: You need to report it to Google. They help you how to cope with this issue.